# Method not converted from objective-c to swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, socketrocket

I need to implement wamp v1 protocol in my swift project. I googled for library MDWamp ([v 1.1.0](https://github.com/mogui/MDWamp/tree/1.1.0)). Also with MDWamp i need SocketRocket ([v 0.3.1-beta2](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket/tree/v0.3.1-beta2)). All installed via cocoapods like this:

```
use_frameworks!

target 'webs' do
    pod 'SocketRocket', '~> 0.3.1-beta2'
    pod 'MDWamp', '~> 1.1.0'
end
```

Then, somewhere in my project i need call the `call` function from MDWamp that 100% exist in MDWamp.h file.

[image]

But when i try to type:

```
var wamp = MDWamp(... // init here
wamp.call(...)
```

no autocomplete happened. It's weird. I decided to go to `MDWamp` class (cmd + click on `MDWamp` class) and search the `call` function and... i didn't found it!

[image]

Any ideas why the `call` function not converted to swift?

Comment: Are they using bridging in that 3rd party lib? If yes, then by using bridging, both swift and obj c can be used within the same project

Comment: Do the other methods convert? Are there any others?

Comment: @dokun1 yes, all others are converted

Comment: Ok. Have you tried rewriting it manually in the header and then seeing if you can use it in your swift implementation?

Comment: I wonder if it's the `args` parameter that is preventing translation.